# What is the importance of Chiddush?

Tags: torah-study, chiddush

I have long taken for granted that it is important to be m'chadesh chiddush (compose new and novel torah insights). However, I realize I have no source for that notion. Is there any source which indicates that it is important to try to come up with chiddushim, or perhaps is simply studying torah without adding any novel interpretation equally as meritorious?

Comment: http://divreichaim.blogspot.com/2009/05/command-to-be-mechadesh-for-right.html points us to the _Haamek Davar_ (_Sh'ela_?) on _Vayikra_ 18:5 for an answer, but I don't have that source handy.

Comment: @msh210 that's a nice post but I wish he would share the location of that source. ironic that it is a big chiddush itself

Comment: It says in the Zohar parsha bereishis (forget the exact place but definitely there) that one who makes chidushim in torah creates worlds.

Comment: @msh210 the source is haamek she'ela 42:10

Comment: @not-vram, great; thanks. If he answers the question and you want to write up his answer here, that'd be a great benefit to the rest of us.

Comment: HaRav Haim Palagi ZS"L wrote about Hiddushim somehwhere. Can't remember. BN I'll search.

Answer (score 3):

[*Tana D've Eliyahu*, *Raba*, near the end of chapter 10](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51880&pgnum=70), reads:

> אשרי מי שמתחדש ד״ת על פיו וכל מי שמתחדש דברי תורה על פיו דומה כמי שמשמיעין אותו מן השמים ואומר לו כך אמר הקב״ה בני בנה לי בית המדרש ששכר הגדול שיש לי באוצרי שלך הוא ובשבילך אני מציל את ישראל

— which I'm having a hard time translating, but it *seems* to mean:

> Happy is he through whose mouth words of Torah are created. Anyone through whose mouth words of Torah are created is like someone who is called from Heaven and told, "God says, 'My son, build me a study hall, for the vast reward in my storehouse is yours, and because of you I rescue the Jews'".

Comment: A tip of the hat to Rabbi Paysach J. Krohn (_Echoes of the Maggid_, page 235) for pointing me to this source.

Comment: possibly 'my son **built** for me...

Comment: @nikmasi, I'd thought of that, but then the change in person (third person to second) to "שלך" strikes me as odd. You may well be right, though.

Comment: I think it means blessed is the person, who has words of Torah introduced on his account. I.e. he is the impetus for more Torah learning. (in the example, through building a study hall).

Comment: @mevaqesh, you may well be right re "on his account" versus "from his mouth" and indeed the study-hall construction makes more sense (to me) that way. But why are you saying "words of Torah introduced" means only more learning and not new words?

Answer (score 1):

נפש החיים שער ד פרק יב:

> וכל שכן חידושין אמיתים דאורייתא המתחדשין ע"י האדם. אין ערוך לגודל נוראות נפלאות ענינם ופעולתם למעלה. שכל מלה ומלה פרטית המתחדשת מפי האדם. קב"ה נשיק לה ומעטר לה. ונבנה ממנה עולם חדש בפ"ע. והן הן השמים החדשים והארץ החדשה שאמר הכתוב. כמ"ש בהקדמת הזוהר ח"א ד, ב
>
> (my translation) How much more so every chiddush in Torah made by man, there is no measure of the greatness of  its awesomeness ... every word of chiddush from the mouth of man, Hashem kisses it and crowns it, and builds from it a new world of its own, and these are the heavens and earth which the verse refers to, as is described in the Zohar

And [see further there](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%A9_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8_%D7%93/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%99%D7%91) for more.

Answer (score 1):

From Mishnat Rebi Aharon 1:203

> The Mesilat Yesharim writes in his introductions for things known and
>   evident are hidden from people due to their being so evident.
>   Therefore it is necessary to expand the matters and contemplate them,
>   namely, the remedy to increase recognition in them is "lechadesh" (to
>   renew something) in the matter. For the chidush (new thing) causes the
>   entire matter to be clearer so that the evident and familiar receive a
>   new light and shine. The sages said (Sotah 3a): "every parsha that was
>   repeated was repeated only for some chidush (new thing) in it. It was
>   possible to say this new chidush in the first parsha. But the benefit
>   of repeating it is when there is a chidush (new thing). The sages
>   already exhorted us [Midrash Vaetchanan on the verse Devarim 6:6]:
>   "And these words, which I command you this day"] - "that they be in
>   your eyes every day like new".
>
> For the old does not mashpia (influence) a man and he is not affected
>   by it. Only by adding a new idea the matter becomes changed entirely.
>   And likewise by expounding an old matter from a different angle they
>   also become as new....

cited [here](http://dafyomireview.com/mesilat.php?d=2e=3). see there for more (bottom of page)

Answer (score 0):

R. Nachman of Breslov was a great advocate of m'chadesh chiddush as long as it didnt interfere with halocha

Comment: Shalom Anthony. Can you quote a passage of a book of Rav Nachman Mibreslav or a talmid? This can improve the answer.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Anthony.

Answer (score 0):

Talmud Chagigah 3a:15

תָּנוּ רַבָּנַן: מַעֲשֶׂה בְּרַבִּי יוֹחָנָן בֶּן בְּרוֹקָה וְרַבִּי אֶלְעָזָר [בֶּן] חִסְמָא שֶׁהָלְכוּ לְהַקְבִּיל פְּנֵי רַבִּי יְהוֹשֻׁעַ בִּפְקִיעִין. אָמַר לָהֶם: מָה חִידּוּשׁ הָיָה בְּבֵית הַמִּדְרָשׁ הַיּוֹם? אָמְרוּ לוֹ: תַּלְמִידֶיךָ אָנוּ וּמֵימֶיךָ אָנוּ שׁוֹתִין. אָמַר לָהֶם: אַף עַל פִּי כֵן, אִי אֶפְשָׁר לְבֵית הַמִּדְרָשׁ בְּלֹא חִידּוּשׁ.

The Sages taught: There was an incident involving Rabbi Yoḥanan ben Beroka and Rabbi Elazar ben Ḥisma, when they went to greet Rabbi Yehoshua in Peki’in. Rabbi Yehoshua said to them: What novel idea was taught today in the study hall? They said to him: We are your students and we drink from your water, i.e., all of our Torah knowledge comes from you, and therefore how can we tell you something you have not already learned? He said to them: Even so, there cannot be a study hall without a novelty.

The Netziv on Leviticus 18:5 (וּשְׁמַרְתֶּ֤ם אֶת־חֻקֹּתַי֙ וְאֶת־מִשְׁפָּטַ֔י אֲשֶׁ֨ר יַֽעֲשֶׂ֥ה אֹתָ֛ם הָֽאָדָ֖ם וָחַ֣י בָּהֶ֑ם אֲנִ֖י יְהוָֹֽה:)

https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Vayikra/18.5#e0n6

אשר יעשה אותם וגו׳ – לפי פי׳ השני דקאי על מצות התורה משמעו אשר יעשה בפועל. וכדאי׳ במשנה דמכות הנ״ל דהיושב ולא עבר עבירה שהגיע לידו דומה כאלו עשה מצוה בפועל. אבל לפי׳ הא׳ דקאי כל עסק התורה פי׳ יעשה יחדש הלכה ע״י עומק עיונו לפי כללי התורה די״ג מדות והויות התלמוד.

understands the warning, "U'shmartem es chukosai v'es mishpatai asher ya'aseh osam ha'adam v'chai bahem" (Leviticus 18:5) not as a general exhortation to observe mitzvos, but as a specific command to be an "oseh", to create and innovate in Torah. We ask Hashem daily in Ahavah Rabbah to give us the ability to "lilmod u'lelameid, lishmor, v'la'asos, u'l'kayeim" -- "la'asos" is distinct from the shmiras hamitzvos of "kiyum" and is connected to the process of limud haTorah.