# What is the procedure for generating a chiddush?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, torah-study, chiddush

Sometimes I see cool things in the parasha that just are not mentioned by the meforshim, that is, I generate what could be called chidushim.

So far I present them by saying "Is X related to Y because ..." but I want to be able to take it the next step further by saying "I think X is related to Y because..."

What is the responsible and permitted method to generate a chidush that a) does not potentially affect halacha b) might possibly affect halacha?

The following question is related but does not answer the question:

[What is the importance of Chiddush?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28738/what-is-the-importance-of-chiddush)

Comment: IIRC (I'm not taking time to look for it now) the _Tif'eres Yisrael_ on _Avos_ addresses this question.